# Logstash overwrite doesn’t happen when message empty

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

logstash 5.3.0

```
filter {
  grok {
    patterns_dir => ["/etc/logstash/patterns"]
    match => [
               "message", "%{NGINXACCESS} %{GREEDYDATA:message}",
               "message", "%{NGINXACCESSAUTH}%{GREEDYDATA:message}",
               "message", "%{NGINXERROR}",
               "message", "%{PHPLOG}%{GREEDYDATA:message}",
               "message", "%{FPMERROR}%{GREEDYDATA:message}",
               "message", "%{SYSLOG5424PRI}%{SYSLOGBASE2} %{GREEDYDATA:message}"
    ]
    overwrite => [ "message" ]
  }
```

I am having an issue here where I have a complete parse here for NGINXACCESSAUTH which leaves me with empty result for %{GREEDYDATA:message} and this not rewriting message field to empty, leaving me with messy outcome of message field being the full rsyslog source message as well as all the tags parsed.

```
program:nginx
logsource:ppdlweb005 
nginx_client:10.175.37.27 
nginx_auth:- 
nginx_time:08/Mar/2018:14:16:24 +0000 
nginx_ident:- 
nginx_response:200
message:<141>Mar 8 14:16:33 ppdlweb005 nginx 10.175.37.27 - - - [08/Mar/2018:14:16:24 +0000] "HEAD /?_=havemercy11 HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "-" "AppleWebkit/534.1 (KHTML) HbbTV/1.4.1 (+DRM;SureSoft-Browser-3.0;T3;0010;1.0;Manhattan-FVPlay;) FVC/2.0(SureSoft-Browser-3.0;Manhattan-FVPlay;)" SUCCESS 0.001 
nginx_bytes:0 
http_user_agent:AppleWebkit/534.1 (KHTML) HbbTV/1.4.1 (+DRM;SureSoft-Browser-3.0;T3;0010;1.0;Manhattan-FVPlay;) FVC/2.0(SureSoft-Browser-3.0;Manhattan-FVPlay;) 
nginx_httpversion:1.1 
@timestamp:March 8th 2018, 14:16:33.000 
nginx_verb:HEAD 
nginx_processing_time:0.001 
fvc_role:auth 
http_referer:- 
fvc_env:staging 
syslog5424_pri:141 
@version:1 
host:ppdlweb005 
nginx_ssl_verify:SUCCESS 
nginx_request:/?_=havemercy11 
timestamp:Mar 8 14:16:33 
_id:AWIF-Hov00VaJHdB36R2 
_type:logs 
_index:logstash-2018.03.08 
_score: -
```

Any idea how to go about this apart from removing part of the pattern so there is something for GREEDYDATA to parse?

Comment: Tried keep_empty_captures => true?

Comment: Well this was simple, thank you very much, did you try to post this as answer?

Comment: Posted the comment as answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `keep_empty_captures => true` to retain the empty message